# How do I dictate @ to siri?

Tags: ios, siri

I'm looking to learn how to dictate @ to siri. If there is a general resource to look up how to find odd characters, so much the better, but in US English I'm not figuring this out by myself.

Comment: Have you seen this?: [Siri User Guide
Tips, tricks and tutorials on using Siri on the iPhone, iPad and Apple Watch.](http://www.siriuserguide.com/siri-dictation-guide/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @ is the **at sign** for siri according to this unofficial guide:

http://www.siriuserguide.com/siri-dictation-guide/

I don't see any official Apple resource but this wikipedia article documenting the [Basic Latin Unicode block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) (which also maps directly to ASCII text) has english pronunciation that works well with Siri.

The things I can't get to work from that table are:

- ^ - circumflex
- _ - low line - (but underline works)

Also, dictating quotes needs to be with the quote on/quote off command and not by dictating when the quotes should be typed.